# Cannot intercept SSL after installing self-signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, intercept

This is something I do usually and works fluently.

I have generated a certificate from Burp proxy and installed on my android (Android 5.1.1) device in order to intercept the communication. 
Unfortunatley, I recieve a warning saying "network may be monitored by an unknown third party", and im not able to navigate to anywhere with SSL on the mobile browser.

Why is this happening? I usually do that and it lets me intercept fluently...

Please notice that no SSL site is working, not a specific app which implements some certificate pinning mechanism.

Comment: *"This is something I do usually and works fluently."* - if it usually works but not this time than you must have done something different. How should we help here if we don't know in detail what you usually do and what you did different this time?

Comment: I have wrote exactly what I do and it is very simple. Installing a certificate on the device to intercept SSL. if you cant help dont flame here.

Comment: You've described that you are doing the same as always but only this time it does not work. Thus obviously something is different what you did. And it is impossible for us to figure out which difference cause the problem if you don't describe what you've done differently.

Comment: You are not "us". And I have described exactly what I do, nevermind if I did it before or not. If you have a solution, help, if not, please stop ruining this post.